# 403 Forbidden on PHP page called with url encoded in a $_GET parameter

Tags: php, query-string

Given hello.php:

```
<?php echo "Hello"; ?>
```

rendering the page works fine and returns **Hello**, however

```
http://example.com/hello.php?test=http%3a//whatever.com
```

returns a 403 Forbidden. But oddly enough, making the first letter of http uppercase works fine:

```
http://example.com/hello.php?test=Http%3a//whatever.com
```

FYI, percent encoding the slashes also 403s:

```
http://example.com/hello.php?test=http%3a%2f%2fwhatever.com
```

I'm beginning to suspect this may be an issue with Passenger (which I use to serve RoR)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is mod_security's 10_asl_rules.conf causing this error.

Comment: can you explain how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your htaccess is picking up on something in that URL and sending forbidden headers. Do you have a .htaccess file?

Comment: sure, but nothing that would affect this.