# URL passed as GET parameter gives 403 forbidden while integrating mTurk API

Tags: php, apache, amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I am trying to integrate mTurk API in one of my sites. I am creating HIT and using EXTERNAL QUESTION, passing my custom PHP web page hosted on my server. Example- http://abc.com/submitanswer.php?var1=testname

Now, on mTruk site, on completion of the task by user, when the user wants to submit the work done to my site, mTurk calls url provided by me in EXTERNAL QUESTION parameter. Additionally, it adds one more parameter - "turkSubmitTo=https://workersandbox.mturk.com" in the url.

So, when request is made for the page it creates a problem and gives 403 - Forbidden. If I directly call this url, then even it gives the same error. But, if I alter any text in value of GET para - turkSubmitTo like : remove "h" from OR remove ":" or such change, the browser nicely displays the page, without any errors..

Tried all possible ways one can think off, there is nothing else left now!

Need help !!!

Thanks !

Varshesh..

Comment: Shouldn't the url be encoded then?

Comment: That portion is not in my control. mTurk is adding that - "turkSubmitTo=https://workersandbox.mturk.com" to the url provided. And they do encode sometimes like - 
turkSubmitTo=https%3A%2F%2Fworkersandbox.mturk.com. Still issue remains the same..

Comment: Seems similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354133/403-forbidden-when-passing-url-in-get-variable?rq=1

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere on this?  I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's a mod_security issue. If you're on hosting provider, you can ask them to provide an exception for you. If it's local, you probably have to do it yourself.