# passing http url as an get method variable - how to?

Tags: query-string, apache

I am trying to do this:

`http://somehost.net/edit.php?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EgHY53dOZ-U`

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access edit.php on this server.

Is there a way to fix this through javascript(jquery), cause I am passing argument through ajax call.

I have tried it this way but without success:

```
$('#videofrm').load('edit.php?url='+encodeURI($(this).siblings('a').attr('href'))
```

Comment: Have you tried to fix the permission issue yet?

Comment: I gave you a website with urlEncode function.. try using that one. Thereby, what does the page says if you load it without any $_GET parameters?

Comment: can you post the part that processes `$_GET['url']`?

Comment: btw it's `encodeURIComponent` not `encodeURI` for this kinda stuff

Comment: @daniel.tosaba: What does the edit.php does?

Comment: for some reason it doesn't like `http` in there and throws a 403, show us how you handle the URL to help you with it

Comment: `http` is fine. It doesn't like `://`, even encoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have permission to access `edit.php`, then it doesn't matter how many different ways you try to request it: you don't have permission.

Fix the permissions on the server, likely using `chmod` if the server is on Linux.

---

**Update**

You have a server configuration issue. I can only replicate the problem when passing the string `://` inside the querystring.

Try writing `AllowEncodedSlashes On` in your httpd config, as per [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462082/how-do-you-configure-apache-php-to-accept-slashes-in-query-strings).

You will then need to make sure you encode your URI properly:

```
http://somehost.net/edit.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv=EgHY53dOZ-U
```

(it looks like your `encodeURI` call should take care of that part)

`AllowEncodedSlashes` [allows](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes) slashes to be present in the query string as long as they're encoded which, for some reason, is *not* the case by default. The docs say that failure produces a 404, not a 403, but I still think that this is the cause.

If you are not able to manipulate configuration options for your webserver, workarounds include:

- Choosing a stand-in term for `http://` like `http!!!` that you will programmatically revert in the PHP script;
- If you *always* use `http://` (as opposed to, say, `ftp://` or some local path), just leave it off the query string entirely and prepend it to the input in your PHP script <sup>(preferred workaround)</sup>.

Hope that helps.

Comment: why would i fix anything? if i put some other format variable like url=stackoverlow everything works just fine

Comment: @daniel.tosaba: I find that unlikely, unless `edit.php` performs an HTTP redirect. Does it?

Comment: it does not. it just needs given data so it can do some database stuff

Comment: @daniel.tosaba: That's remarkable. To solve this, we'd need to know _exactly_ what your `edit.php` is doing, and about any `.htaccess` definitions you may have. We just don't have enough information.

Comment: thank you very much for valuable answer. i've just found out that my type of account doesn't allow this, so i will have to do some trickery job. thanks again!!

Comment: @daniel: No worries. If you're a serious web developer, I recommend getting hold of a server that you can administer properly. :) In the meantime, as Neel suggests, you can find some other way to represent the URL (be it by using some custom string to stand in for `http://`, or by taking off the `http://` entirely and "adding it in post-production"). I have incorporated this into my answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You should fix the chmoding issues on the server.

### Edit

What your edit.php doing ? If it redirecting to somewhere else ? then echo the result url before redirecting.

You can follow Tomalak Geret'kal if you want/can rewrite the .htaccess. otherwise you need to pass the url without the `http://` part and prepend an `http://` on edit.php

Comment: It's a bit premature to conclude that it's simply a filesystem permissions issue.

Comment: why would i fix anything? if i put some other format variable like url=stackoverlow everything works just fine

Comment: You should mention the same in your question too

Comment: if the url have the `http://` at the begening then only it shows 403 and 404. Hope you got the hint

Comment: how would you fix it, without taking http part off?

Comment: as a quick solution you may send without http:// part and add the http:// part in your edit.php.

Comment: many thanks for noticing this. i will have to do some tricks around this one. nice tip!!

Comment: @Neel: Not just the beginning, and not just `http`.