# FileName from url excluding querystring

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a url :

```
http://www.xyz.com/a/test.jsp?a=b&c=d
```

How do I get `test.jsp` of it ?

Comment: `/a\/(.*)\?/.exec('http://www.xyz.com/a/test.jsp?a=b&c=d')[1]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var path = document.location.pathname,
    file = path.substr(path.lastIndexOf('/'));
```

**Reference:** [`document.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location), [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr), [`lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf)

Comment: This wont remove after querystring .

Comment: @user: The query string is not in `pathname` anyway. It only returns the path. Have a look at the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I wont just show you the answer, but I'll give you direction to it. First... strip out everything after the "?" by using a string utility and location.href.status (that will give you the querystring). Then what you will be left with will be the URL; get everything after the last "/" (hint: lastindexof).

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression.

var urlVal = 'http://www.xyz.com/a/test.jsp?a=b&c=d';
var result = /a\/(.*)\?/.exec(urlVal)[1]

the regex returns an array, use [1] to get the test.jsp

Answer (score 0):

This method does not depend on pathname:

```
    <script>
        var url = 'http://www.xyz.com/a/test.jsp?a=b&c=d';
        var file_with_parameters = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        var file = file_with_parameters.substr(0, file_with_parameters.lastIndexOf('?')); 
        // file now contains "test.jsp"
    </script>
```

Comment: this wouldn't work if the query string had a / in it.
i.e.: var url = '...www.xyz.com/a/test.jsp?a=b&c=d&file=/blah.html

Comment: Slashes in the query string need to be encoded, or the URL is invalid.

Comment: Except in the rare case that the server is specifically configured to allow them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462082/how-do-you-configure-apache-php-to-accept-slashes-in-query-strings

Comment: I've never ran into a problem with slashes in the query string... (on Apache). Is it possible that the browser autoescapes them?

Answer (score 0):

```
var your_link = "http://www.xyz.com/a/test.jsp?a=b&c=d";

// strip the query from the link
your_link = your_link.split("?");
your_link = your_link[0];

// get the the test.jsp or whatever is there
var the_part_you_want = your_link.substring(your_link.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/\/([^/]+)$/.exec(window.location.pathname)[1]
```