# JavaScript get last URL segment

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to get the Last segment of the URL (omitting any parameters). Also url may or may not include the last '/' character

for example

```
http://Home/Billing/Index.html?param1=2&another=2
should result in: Index.html

http://Home/Billing/Index.html/
should result in: Index.html
```

I've tried this but i can't get how to check for the last /

```
ar href = window.location.pathname;
            var value = href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

Comment: something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302306/how-to-pull-the-file-name-from-a-url-using-javascript-jquery ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [FileName from url excluding querystring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035352/filename-from-url-excluding-querystring)

Comment: both of these don't take under account the last '/' character. Pls take a look at example 2 I posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like?

```
window.location.pathname.split('?')[0].split('/').filter(function (i) { return i !== ""}).slice(-1)[0]
```

1. Split on '?' to throw out any query string parameters
2. Get the first of those splits
3. Split on '/'.
4. For all those splits, filter away all the empty strings
5. Get the last one remaining

Answer (score 1):

@psantiago answer works great. If you want to do the same but using RegEx you can implement as follows:

```
var r = /(\/([A-Za-z0-9\.]+)(\??|\/?|$))+/;
r.exec("http://Home/Billing/Index.html?param1=2&another=2")[2]; //outputs: Index.html 
r.exec("http://Home/Billing/Index.html/"); //outputs: Index.html
```

In my opinion, the above code is more efficient and cleaner than using split operations.