# There is a / in my OAuth2 access token in php

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

Okay, here is my issue:

In my Google OAuth2 Access token there is a /
This may not seem like a big deal, but when doing the callback I get a lot of issues.
eg: callback.php?code=lfjhl/djbj (that isn't my real token, but it does contain a /)

but the issue there is it is trying to then take me to index.php/djbj and obviously I get 404.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is not surprising to find / in returned OAuth code. You just need to handle it safely. This is more of webserver config or url parsing problem and you need to provide further details of your settings.

Comment: RFC 3986 actually specifies that including '/' without escaping is quite valid noting that "Beware that some older, erroneous implementations may not handle such data correctly" (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986). The following discussion may include some pointers on how to resolve: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462082/how-do-you-configure-apache-php-to-accept-slashes-in-query-strings